# What is the gradle equivalent of maven's exec plugin for running Java apps?

Tags: gradle

With maven I can create a project, set up my pom with its dependencies, write a class with a main method and then to run it type:

```
mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=thornydev.App
```

What is the gradle equivalent of doing this?

I can do `gradle build`, which builds a jar file for me, but if the main class has any dependencies on other jars, just running the jar won't work without setting up the classpath.  Can the gradle java plugin run the app and set up the classpath for me?

I'm looking for a command line solution for simple one-off uses, not IDE integration (I know how to do that).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

The easiest solution is to use the [Application Plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html), which among other things provides a `run` task. To make the main class configurable from the command line, you'll have to set `mainClassName` to the value of some system (or project) property, and then pass that property from the command line:

```
apply plugin: "application"

mainClassName = System.getProperty("mainClass")
```

Now you can run the application with `gradle run -DmainClass=thornydev.App`.

Comment: As of gradle 1.10, passing `-DmainClass` to choose different Class with `main` has not effect. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358466

Answer (score 3):

I needed to run a Java program as part of the build process, and the application plugin came with too much baggage.

I did fidde with the application plugin, but in the end I used the much less "invasive" [JavaExec plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.html).

I have a class file `MyObfuscator.class` in the `build.outputDirectory` and before I had a `pom.xml` like this, which ran code obfuscation in the build directory with two parameters:

```xml
<project>
    ...
    <build>
        ...
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>obfuscate</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>java</executable>
                            <workingDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</workingDirectory>
                            <arguments>
                                <argument>-Djava.library.path=.</argument>
                                <argument>-classpath</argument>
                                <argument>${project.build.outputDirectory}:lib.jar</argument>
                                <argument>MyObfuscator</argument>
                                <argument>HELLO</argument>
                                <argument>GOODBYE</argument>
                            </arguments>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
    ...
</project>
```

I boiled it down to this thing in Gradle:

```java
apply plugin: "java"

// ...

task obfuscate(type: JavaExec) {
    // Make sure it runs after compilation and resources.
    // Skip this if that's not a requirement.
    dependsOn classes
    
    // run in the buildDir (this requirement was what
    // made a simple "doLast" infeasible)
    workingDir = file(buildDir)
    classpath = files([
        "${buildDir}/classes",
        "${buildDir}/resources/main/lib.jar"
    ])
    main = "MyObfuscator"
}
```

If you need parameterized execution like in the Maven example above, then add a few lines to the task:

```java
task obfuscate(type: JavaExec) {
    // ... (as above)
    
    // Set PARAM1 to a default value when it's not
    // defined on the command line
    if(!project.hasProperty("PARAM1")) {
        ext.PARAM1 = "HELLO"
    }
    // PARAM1 is dynamic and PARAM2 is static, always "GOODBYE"
    args = [PARAM1, "GOODBYE"]
}
```

Then depend the `assemble` task on `obfuscate` (put this line anywhere below the `obfuscate` task definition):

```java
assemble.dependsOn obfuscate
```

Or let the (earlier) `jar` task depend on it. See the graph at the bottom of [this docs section here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/java_plugin.html#sec:java_tasks) for more ideas on where to inject this.

You can then call gradle like `gradle build -PPARAM1=HELLO` to run a parameterized build.

Answer (score 0):

If my plugin is :

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>run-benchmarks</id>
      <phase>integration-test</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>exec</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <classpathScope>test</classpathScope>
        <executable>java</executable>
        <arguments>
          <argument>-classpath</argument>
          <classpath />
          <argument>org.openjdk.jmh.Main</argument>
          <argument>.*</argument>
        </arguments>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
```

what will be the equivalent one in gradle ?