# Gradle to execute Java class (without modifying build.gradle)

Tags: java, gradle, execution

There is [simple Eclipse plugin](https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/tree/master/org.nodeclipse.enide.gradle) to run Gradle, that just uses command line way to launch gradle.

What is gradle analog for maven compile and run
`mvn compile exec:java -Dexec.mainClass=example.Example`

This way any project with `gradle.build` could be run.

UPDATE: There was similar question [What is the gradle equivalent of maven's exec plugin for running Java apps?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350757/what-is-the-gradle-equivalent-of-mavens-exec-plugin-for-running-java-apps?rq=1) asked before, but solution suggested altering every project `build.gradle`

```
package runclass;

public class RunClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("app is running!");
    }
}
```

Then executing `gradle run -DmainClass=runclass.RunClass`

```
:run FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':run'.
> No main class specified
```

Comment: Probable duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16350757/what-is-the-gradle-equivalent-of-mavens-exec-plugin-for-running-java-apps?rq=1

Comment: Use command : gradle run

Answer (score 163, accepted):

There is no direct equivalent to `mvn exec:java` in gradle, you need to either apply the `application` plugin or have a `JavaExec` task.

### `application` plugin

Activate the plugin:

```
plugins {
    id 'application'
    ...
}
```

Configure it as follows:

```
application {
    mainClassName = project.hasProperty("mainClass") ? project.getProperty("mainClass") : "NULL"
}
```

On the command line, write

```
$ gradle -PmainClass=Boo run
```

### `JavaExec` task

Define a task, let's say `execute`:

```
task execute(type:JavaExec) {
   main = project.hasProperty("mainClass") ? getProperty("mainClass") : "NULL"
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

To run, write `gradle -PmainClass=Boo execute`. You get

```
$ gradle -PmainClass=Boo execute
:compileJava
:compileGroovy UP-TO-DATE
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:execute
I am BOO!
```

`mainClass` is a property passed in dynamically at command line. `classpath` is set to pickup the latest classes.

---

If you do not pass in the `mainClass` property, both of the approaches fail as expected.

```
$ gradle execute

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'xxxx/build.gradle' line: 4

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating root project 'Foo'.
> Could not find property 'mainClass' on task ':execute'.
```

Comment: Thanks for letting know, but in this case `build.gralde` also needds to be modified, also now there is hard-coded classpath to care about.

Comment: You have to modify `build.gradle`, the `classpath` is hardcoded to pick up the [tag:java] classes from your `build.gradle` [tag:java] source classpath. Even when you run `mvn exec:java` the classpath is set to pick up the java source files in the current maven directory. In the `JavaExec` task, I have done the same. Change the `classpath` for your [tag:java] source and the class path will change automatically. There is no - `mvn exec:java` equivalent in `gradle` you need to either apply the `application` plugin or have a `JavaExec` task.

Comment: OR the other option is you write your own plugin to do this and even then you have to change the build.gradle to pick up your plugin.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is complete answer. Now with `gradle -PmainClass=runclass.RunClass execute` I can select which class to execute.

Comment: If someone knows how to do the above for android studio/gradle that'd be great, because in my case sourceSets.main does not exist. Apparently android.sourceSets.main exists, but no runtimeClasspath after that...

Comment: I just tried this and it seems that after adding `task execute(...` to build.gradle, every other task fails with the same error message telling that gradle expects mainClass to be passed along. I can't do clean or build.

Comment: @Nirei Substitute `main = mainClass` with `main = getProperty("mainClass")` and it will no longer yell at you.

Comment: @Adidishen, that didn't work for me. However this does: `mainClassName = findProperty("mainClass") ?: ""`

Comment: this still breaks `gradle build`, see my answer below.

Comment: `mainClassName = project.hasProperty("mainClass") ? getProperty("mainClass") : "NULL"` does not work for me. `getProperty("mainClass")` needs to be changed to `project.getProperty("mainClassName")`. I am using Gradle 6.5.1.

Comment: Execution failed for task ':execute'.
> Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 1

Comment: Minor update for deprecated method in Gradle 8.0, "The JavaApplication.setMainClassName(String) method has been deprecated. This is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 8.0. Use #getMainClass().set(...) instead."
->
`getMainClass().set(project.hasProperty("mainClass") ? project.getProperty("mainClass") : "NULL")`

Answer (score 146):

You just need to use the [Gradle Application plugin](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/application_plugin.html):

```
apply plugin:'application'
mainClass = "org.gradle.sample.Main"
```

And then simply `gradle run`.

As Teresa points out, you can also configure `mainClass` as a system property and run with a command line argument.

Comment: That would require to hard code every such class into `build.graldle`. But I have project with a lot of util classes, that every has main method.

Comment: And you are sure 1) the fully qualified class name is correct 2) you put the right property name in your build file--*e.g.* `System.getProperty("mainClass")`, 3) the source code is where it is supposed to be according to convention, 4) it all works when you put `RunClass` in the build file?

Comment: It only works if `build.gradle` has `mainClassName = "runclass.RunClass"` . Parameter `-DmainClass` has no effect: 

`gradle run -DmainClass=runclass.RunClass2` executes the hard-coded mainclass.

Comment: If you do both (build file approach and property approach), I actually don't know which takes precedence. You should either find that answer or not do both in your testing.

Comment: @PaulVerest Here's what I did: ```ext.mainClass = project.hasProperty('mainClass') ? project.getProperty('mainClass') : 'org.gradle.sample.Main' ; apply plugin:'application' ; mainClassName = ext.mainClass```

Now when you do `gradle -PmainClass=Foo run` it should use `Foo` as the main class.

Comment: to pass args: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604283/gradle-task-pass-arguments-to-java-application

Answer (score 31):

Expanding on First Zero's answer, I'm guess you want something where you can also run `gradle build` without errors.

Both `gradle build` and `gradle -PmainClass=foo runApp` work with this:

```
task runApp(type:JavaExec) {
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    main = project.hasProperty("mainClass") ? project.getProperty("mainClass") : "package.MyDefaultMain"
}
```

where you set your default main class.

Comment: Imho this should be the accepted answer. Using FirstZero's or Vidya's method will cause other tasks to complain due to the main class not being specified.

Comment: Matt's approach to setting the main value also works for the application plugin.  I am using it with the Gradle Kotlin DSL:

`plugins {
    application
};

application {
    mainClassName = if (project.hasProperty("mainClass")) project.properties.get("mainClass").toString() else "Foo"
}`

Comment: @Matt This approach breaks my simple Java program that uses a `Scanner` to read `nextLine()`. Any thought on a fix for this? Keep getting "no line found" when running using runApp.

Comment: To anyone reading this in the future, I used ` standardInput = System.in` to allow my gradle execution to still pass in input

Answer (score 1):

You can parameterise it and pass  gradle clean build -Pprokey=goodbye

```
task choiceMyMainClass(type: JavaExec) {
     group = "Execution"
    description = "Run Option main class with JavaExecTask"
    classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath

    if (project.hasProperty('prokey')){
        if (prokey == 'hello'){
            main = 'com.sam.home.HelloWorld'
        } 
        else if (prokey == 'goodbye'){
            main = 'com.sam.home.GoodBye'
        }
    } else {
            println 'Invalid value is enterrd';

       // println 'Invalid value is enterrd'+ project.prokey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If using Kotlin DSL and with gradle8.5 (or perhaps even newer ones), it seems I need to write it like this:

If you use "application" plugin, write in `build.gradle.kts` and
run as: `./gradlew run`

```kotlin
plugins {
    application
}

application {
    mainClass.set("org.example.Main")
}
```

Or, if you use the "java" plugin, this defines a custom task called "runMe" via the `JavaExec` task type, and it does the same thing as above when running `./gradlew runMe`. The good thing is now you can write more tasks if you have more classes with main methods.

```kotlin
plugins {
    java
}


tasks.register<JavaExec>("runMe") {
    classpath = sourceSets["main"].runtimeClasspath
    mainClass = "org.example.Main"
}
```

More about [JavaExec](https://docs.gradle.org/current/kotlin-dsl/gradle/org.gradle.api.tasks/-java-exec/index.html). The groovy example in the API doc is not very helpful...