# Can Gradle execute JavaScript (instead of Java entry point)?

Tags: java, javascript, gradle, nashorn, avatarjs

Can Gradle possibly execute JavaScript?

While there is no standard plugins for javascript, is it possible to make something like `JavaExec`

```
task execute(type:JavaExec) {
   main = mainClass
   classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

Reason: with Java 8 Nashorn and Avatar.js project application entry point can be JavaScript file, not Java.

Searches for Gradle JavaScript plugin gives web oriented solutions, like https://github.com/eriwen/gradle-js-plugin

related to [Gradle to execute Java class (without modifying build.gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358466/gradle-to-execute-java-class-without-modifying-build-gradle)