# launch Java program from gradle

Tags: java, android, gradle

Lets say I have a compiled Java program called launchProgramm.class.
It takes 2 parameters of String.

And I have a gradle build script

```
android {
...
}
```

What I need is to launch my launchProgramm from gradle script and give it 2 parameters. How can I do that?

Listen, I need to do some things with .apk file after all gradle build is finished. Lets say I want to copy it to another directory or open it and change some files. Is ip possible?

Comment: run from gradle??? i think its just for dependencies
what are you trying to accomplish? starting with android and want to run your app??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358466/gradle-to-execute-java-class-without-modifying-build-gradle

Comment: This question is just to broad.

Comment: Bart Hofma, lets say that java .class does something with .apk  file. That's why I need that.

Comment: See `JavaExec` in the [Gradle Build Language Reference](http://gradle.org/docs/current/dsl/index.html).