# Converting Ant Script to Gradle (WSDL2)

Tags: java, gradle, ant

I currently have the following target in ant script for a Java project:

```
<target name="axis wrapper">
        <java classname="org.apache.axis.wsdl.WSDL2Java"
              fork="true">
            <classpath>
                <fileset dir="lib">
                    <include name="**/*.jar"/>
                </fileset>
            </classpath>
            <arg line="-D ${web.loc}/Hello.asmx?WSDL -o src"/>
        </java>
    </target>
```

I have been trying to convert it to Gradle but keep running into the following error from using ant.taskdef:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':genWrapperClasses'.

  > No main class specified
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

When I try to create a Gradle task based on the Ant target I get an error that tells me some part of the jars are missing.

I was wondering if anyone knew the best way to either invoke ant from Gradle or make a custom Gradle task that would make it work.

Note:

- All of the proper .jar files are in the right place
- I have set my environment variable for Axis set to point to the directory where those jars are located.

Comment: Regarding the `No main class specified` error, see [Gradle to execute Java class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358466/gradle-to-execute-java-class-without-modifying-build-gradle).

Comment: I'd give the [wsdl2java gradle plugin](https://github.com/nilsmagnus/wsdl2java) a shot that likely  provides the functionality you are looking for.