# Can't find Main when executing a Java class from Gradle

Tags: java, gradle

I've  been attempting to run a java main from Gradle however Gradle keeps giving me the error

> Execution failed for task ':myTask'
>
> No main class specified

I've attached the code below

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDirs 'src/myPackage/downloadupdater'
            srcDirs 'src/myPackage/downloadupdater/util' 
            srcDirs 'src/myPackage/downloadupdater/dao'
        }
        // output.classesDir = "/bin"
    }
}

task myTask(dependsOn : compileJava, type : JavaExec){
    group = "Custom"
    description = "Acquires the weekly stats"

    doLast{
        classpath = sourceSets.main.output.classesDir
        main = "myPackage.SomeClass"
        args "-w"
    }
}
```

The java class I'm calling is:

```
package myPackage
public class SomeClass{

    private static DownloadUpdater updater;

    public static void main (String [] args) {

        updater = new DownloadUpdater();
    
        updater.whichStatistics(args[0]);
    
        updater.setCalendar();
    
        updater.secureWorkbook();
    
        updater.getStatistics();

    }
}
```

After building, my directories come up with a build-classes-java-main-myPackage but gradle still can't find the main class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either move java source files to src/main/java instead of just src. Or set

```
sourceSet properly
sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs = ['src']
```

and use

```
task execute(type:JavaExec) {
main = "myPackage.SomeClass"
classpath = sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}
```

for more refer : [Gradle to execute Java class (without modifying build.gradle)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21358466/gradle-to-execute-java-class-without-modifying-build-gradle)

Comment: Realized my mistake, I was setting the main and classpath inside a doLast block which was throwing an error when trying to configure the task as a Java Executable. Once moved out of the doLast block and allowed to run during configuration phase, everything worked out. Thanks!

Comment: Error:(38, 1) A problem occurred evaluating root project 'MyProject'.
> Could not get unknown property 'sourceSets' for task ':execute' of type org.gradle.api.tasks.JavaExec.