# Running Gradle application with parameters in NetBeans

Tags: java, netbeans, parameters, gradle

I want to run Gradle application with my own parameter in NetBeans.

Example:

```
java - jar NameOfJarFile -MyParametere valueOfParameter
```

And what I must do to run my application with that parameter?

Answer (score -10, accepted):

Right Click your project > properties > select Run in LHS panel > in Arguments textfield - enter parameters with spaces in between.

[image]

Comment: The above is a screenshot of a NetBeans project that does **not** use the Gradle plugin.  The OP explicitely addressed a Gradle issue with his NetBeans environment.

Answer (score 3):

Although this is an old thread, it might be interesting to mention that I also had this problem using Netbeans and the Gradle plugin and I found 2 solutions, one of them a 'final' one.

- Solution 1: ***not final***

  - I added the following line to my `build.gradle` file:

    `cmdLineArgs = '-v -test'`

    That seems to do the job.

    When I do a normal ***Run Main Project*** or ***Debug Main Project*** in NetBeans, all goes well.  I get the two parameters as arguments to my `main` class.

    **!!!However!!!**: I get an error when I try to run a ***Clean and Build Main Project***.  The error is pointing to the `cmdLineArgs` line I added to my `build.gradle` file.  This is the error message I get:

    `A problem occurred evaluating root project 'PublicApiCheckerWithGradle'.
    Could not set unknown property 'cmdLineArgs' for root project 'PublicApiCheckerWithGradle' of type org.gradle.api.Project.`

    I still don't know why this is...

    If someone has a better Gradle understanding than me and knows what causes this strange behaviour, I'm interested to know...
- Solution 2: ***final***

  - Right-click on the NetBeans project, select ***Properties*** and then select ***Custom Variables*** in the ***Categories:*** section of the dialogue box that opens
  - Add the following line in the Custom Variables: section: `cmd-line-args=-v -test`
  - Close the dialogue box

    Now I can clean and rebuild, build and debug without any issues.  The two arguments are always provided to my `main` method.

Hopefully it helps someone else too.

Best.

Answer (score 1):

I realize this is an older thread, but I've just spent most of an afternoon trying to resolve this. Here's what I came up with after pulling parts of various solutions together.

1. In your `build.gradle file`, add the following:

> ```
> tasks.named('run') {
>     if ( project.hasProperty("cmdArgs") ) {
>         args Eval.me(cmdArgs)
>     }
> }
> ```

2. Right click on the project and select ***Properties*** -> ***Configurations***
3. Clone the default configuration (I named my new configuration `default_cli`)

[Project Properties - Configurations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXwmo.png)

4. Edit your new configuration adding the command line parameters you want to pass to the application as an array called cmdArgs in Properties. In my case, I added `cmdArgs=['-c','config.json']`

[Editing configuration settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2aBf.png)

5. Activate your new configuration and run your application. You should now see the parameters in your `main` method `args` array:

[Args array values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0QKu.png)

Answer (score 0):

Ninad's answer is not valid, since the question was for a Gradle project.  For Gradle projects, the project properties dialog doesn't have those options.  Instead it has:

[image]

Here is what the Project Properties dialog shows:

[image]
Unfortunately, this is a question I also have.  I have attempted to add a Custom Task that supplies the arguments, but when I do, I get a gradle build error which is attempting to run my first argument as a gradle task.  It doesn't seem possible to supply arguments in a NetBeans gradle project.

I tried a workaround by going to the command line and running: "gradle jar" to create a jar.  Then I tried the standard method of running a jar: "java -jar jarname.jar arg1 arg2" and I get an error from java that:

```
no main manifest attribute, in jarName.jar
```

Comment: You can use Custom Tasks to pass properties to the build process and modify your build.gradle to pass those properties to your application.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689054/problems-passing-system-properties-and-parameters-when-running-java-class-via-gr