# Why won't Gradle pass runtime args to Groovy?

Tags: gradle, groovy, system-properties

Gradle 2.14 and Groovy 2.4.7 here. I have the following Groovy:

```
@Slf4j
class Driver {
    static void main(String[] args) {
        log.info("Fizz prop value is: ${System.properties['fizz']}.")
    }
}
```

I'm using the Gradle Application plugin. When I run:

```
./gradlew run -Pfizz=buzz
```

I get he following console output:

> [main] INFO com.me.myapp.Driver - Fizz prop value is: null.

Why does my app think the `fizz` property is `null`, when I am passing its value as `buzz` on the command-line?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689054/problems-passing-system-properties-and-parameters-when-running-java-class-via-gr

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27604283/gradle-task-pass-arguments-to-java-application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing it with `-P` which are properties for gradle

Try passing it with `-D`

Comment: Thanks @tim_yates (+1) - but `./gradlew run -Dfizz=buzz` still produces the same output (`null`).

Answer (score 0):

try without the System.properties and passing -Pfizz=buzz:

```
log.info("Fizz prop value is: ${fizz}.")
```