# Using shell script to pass args to Java

Tags: java, bash, gradle, args

I have a Java project with gradle. This project has a main method.

I know I can run the main method using `./gradlew run` but I cannot pass args to the Java main method using this function

I want to create a single-word bash script like `./runMyCode` that can accept args such as `./runMyCode hello.txt -f` which will be eventually be passed to the java application.

However I am unable to do this. PLease help me...

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29382636/2504962) is what you are looking for.

Comment: I kinda do not want to use the Pargs=... or somehow disguise that into a bash script ?

Comment: You definitely can hide it in bash script. ```#!/bin/bash

function join_by { local d=$1; shift; echo -n "$1"; shift; printf "%s" "${@/#/$d}"; }
args=$(join_by "', '" $@)
gradlew run -PappArgs="[\'$args\']"
```
```./myscript arg1 arg2``` will call the following command:
```gradlew run -PappArgs="['arg1', 'arg2']"```
Note that this approach requires the specific run task in your .gradle file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could [build an executable jar with gradle](https://www.mkyong.com/gradle/gradle-create-a-jar-file-with-dependencies/). Then your `runMyCode` script would look like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

java -jar my-code.jar "$@"
```

And you can use as you wished: `./runMyCode hello.txt -f`.