# Pass command line parameters into run task

Tags: gradle

https://stackoverflow.com/a/23689696/1757491

I started using some info from the proposed solution from the above answer:
Application Plugin Approach

(build.gradle)

```
 apply plugin: 'application'

 mainClassName = "com.mycompany.MyMain"
 run { 
    /* Need to split the space-delimited value in the exec.args */
   args System.getProperty("exec.args").split()    
}
```

Command Line:

```
gradle run -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

it works great for its intended purpose but seems to have a side effect.  It makes sense to pass in the command line arguments for run but I have to pass them in for every task for example:

```
gradle tasks -Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

If I leave out the

```
-Dexec.args="arg1 arg2 arg3"
```

I get

```
"build failed with an exception"
Where:path\build.gradle line:18 which if where my run{ } is.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can solve it a two different ways:

**First**:

`exec.args` property can be read directly in the main class - so there's no need to configure `args` in `run` closure at all.

**Second**:

Just *if* it:

```
execArgs = System.getProperty('exec.args') 
if(execArgs)    
   args = execArgs.split()
```

Edited by Question Asker:
using if does work but I had to change the syntax slightly.

```
if(System.getProperty("exec.args") != null) {
    args System.getProperty("exec.args").split()
}
```