# Set variable to Gadle build file

Tags: gradle

This is kind of a follow-up question to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30775105/get-the-git-working-branch-in-gradle-on-jenkins) one.

I want to "know" from which branch may Android app was built during the execution of the Gradle `build.gradle` file and add the branch name to the `versionName` of my app.

This is my naive approach:

```
apply plugin: 'android'

def branch ="test";

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

    // ..

    buildTypes {

        debug {
            minifyEnabled false;
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix " branch: " + "$branch"
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }

    }

}

task setArgs << {

   branch =  "$word1"

}

task showArgs << {
    println "$branch"
}
```

When I execute:

```
gradlew setArgs -Pword1=mybranch showArgs
```

the branch variable is set and "mybranch" is logged in the console on execution of showArgs.

But when I execute

```
gradlew setArgs -Pword1=mybranch build
```

the branch variable is still the default String "test" and therefore useless in the `versionNameSuffix`.

What's the best way to get this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because the line

```
versionNameSuffix " branch: " + "$branch"
```

is executed during the configuration phase, when all the tasks are configured.

Then, when this phase is done and gradle knows all the tasks and their dependencies, setArgs is executed, and the following line is executed:

```
branch =  "$word1"
```

You could simply remove the setArgs task and do

```
versionNameSuffix " branch: $word1"
```

or, if you want the default value of the branch to be "test" when no property word1 is passed:

```
versionNameSuffix(' branch: ' + (project.hasProperty('word1') ? project.property('word1') : 'test'))
```

Comment: Passing the branch string directly to the build command works, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think a better approach to this would be to use a [`gradle.properties`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html) file to store the branch name - this way you don't have to provide it whenever you invoke Gradle.

**build.gradle:**

```
apply plugin: 'android'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion '22.0.0'

    // ..
    buildTypes {
        debug {
            minifyEnabled false;
            applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
            versionNameSuffix " branch: " + "$branch"
            debuggable true
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}
```

**gradle.properties**

```
branch=mybranch
```

Comment: But that would mean I would have to 'statically' put the branch name into the properties file, right?

Comment: Ideall, yes - but since it's a branch you can have a different `gradle.properties` per branch. You can, however, also provide it with `-Pbranch=mybranch`