# Gradle: increase heap size for java process started by gradle run task

Tags: java, gradle, heap-memory

I have a gradle task which starts a java project. Basically like this:

```
gradle run -PmainClass=package.path.ServiceMain
```

Now, I want to increase the heap for the java process started by gradle because the standard heap size is too small. The problem is that I succeed only to increase the size of the gradle process, not the size of the java process which is launched by the gradle project.
I check the heap size with this command in my Java code:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().totalMemory()
```

I tested this check and it is valid to use it like this. But it shows me that gradle starts my Java process always with the same heap size.

I experimented with these options:

```
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='-Xmx1024m -Xms512m'
GRADLE_OPTS='-Xmx1024m -Xms512m'
JAVA_OPTS='-Xmx1024m -Xms512m'
```

No success.

I also tried this:

```
gradle run -PmainClass=package.path.ServiceMain -DXmx1024m -DXms512m
```

Still, no success.

Of course, I already searched the web but I found only some hints saying that I could modify the `build.gradle` file. Unfortunately, this is not what I want/can.

**I need to specify the java heap size for my java program on the command line when starting it by a gradle run task** (due to the actual project structure).

Thanks in advance for support. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It's not possible without modifying the `build.gradle` script.

Comment: If you relax your requirement on `build.gradle` you can find nice solutions here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689054/problems-passing-system-properties-and-parameters-when-running-java-class-via-gr

Comment: Thanks for the hint charlie_pl, but from what I understand the post is about program arguments, not JVM arguments. Or do I miss something?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

As *@Opal* states above it is **not possible**.

The easiest/simplest alternative I could find (for now) is to add this little snippet to the `build.gradle` file:

```
tasks.withType(JavaExec) {
    jvmArgs = ['-Xms512m', '-Xmx512m']
}
```

Alternatively, the environment variable `_JAVA_OPTIONS` the  can be used.
Even better: the environment variable `JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS`; the content of this variable will be used as (additional) JVM options.

Thanks *@ady* for the hints.

Comment: For this particular question, the env variables are best. But regarding editing the build.gradle, while tasks.withType.. and not simply `run { jvmArgs = ...}`? Reference: https://blog.jakubholy.net/2020/customizing-gradle-run-task/

Comment: @JakubHolý: Indeed, this might be also a possibility. But then it is limited to the run task and it needs to be copied to the test task (if it's needed there), right?

Answer (score 7):

Use this command in Linux: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms4000m -Xmx8000m"` where values 4000 and 8000 can be changed. Instead of JAVA_OPTS use _JAVA_OPTIONS

---

Old answer:
You can set or increase memory usage limits (or other JVM arguments) used for Gradle builds and the Gradle Daemon by editing $GRADLE_USER_HOME/.gradle/gradle.properties (~/.gradle/gradle.properties by default), and setting org.gradle.jvmargs:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx2024m -XX:MaxPermSize=512m
```

Source: https://riptutorial.com/gradle/example/11911/tuning-jvm-memory-usage-parameters-for-gradle

Comment: This seem to relate to the gradle process. What I need to modify is the JVM params of the process started by the gradle process.

Comment: I see, then you can use this command in linux: `export _JAVA_OPTIONS="-Xms4000m -Xmx8000m"` where values 4000 and 8000 can be changed. Instead of `JAVA_OPTS` use `_JAVA_OPTIONS`.

Comment: But in this case I must tell the gradle task (somehow in the build.gradle?) that it should evaluate this parameter and apply it when starting the Java process for the application, right?
Ir is the `_JAVA_OPTIONS` param evaluated always automatically?

Comment: The _JAVA_OPTIONS param is evaluated automatically.

Comment: WOW!  "export _JAVA_OPTIONS" was exactly what I needed to pass a -javaagent=/mypath/myjavaagent.jar argument to the JVM when running gradlew.  Thank you for this answer @ady!   If I just set "export JAVA_OPTIONS" then the values are passed only to Gradle and are NOT passed on to the JVM.

Comment: Credit to @ady again:  I see that JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS is also available and documented: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/envvars002.html

Comment: Using _JAVA_OPTIONS over JAVA_OPS to set these flags is what I have been looking for.  This was surprisingly hard to find.