# Intellij fails to set System property in run configuration within Run Configuration

Tags: java, intellij-idea, jvm

I am passing in System variables using IntelliJ's Run/Debug Configuration tool as follows:

```
Tasks: clean headlessTest
VM options: -Denv=test -DstoreCode=189 -Ddept=apparel
Arguments: -PdepartmentJourney=department_journey
Environment variables: UI_USERNAME=test;UI_PASSWORD=12345...//These are passed in the pipeline script in CI
```

This issues the local Gradle command of:

```
./gradlew clean headlessTest -Denv=test -DstoreCode=189 -Ddept=apparel -PdepartmentJourney=department_journey --no-daemon
```

And in my CI pipeline:

```
def setEnvironmentVariables(){
env.UI_USERNAME = getFromSecrets....
env.UI_PASSWORD = getFromSecrets....
}

./gradlew clean headlessTest -Denv=${env.ENVIRONMENT} - DstoreCode=${env.storeCode} -Ddept=${env.dept} -PdepartmentJourney=department_journey --no-daemon
```

I assume this calls the System.setProperty(String key, String value) method at runtime.

When I debug the code using `getProperty` only the `storeCode` value is set, with `dept` being set to null.

I am using the same `getProperty(String key)` method for each.

Running from the Terminal and in a pipeline also sees the apparel == null.

Is there an obvious reason?

Comment: I actually cannot reproduce that behavior. Could you please specify how exactly you set your properties in IntelliJ's configuration and the run command IntelliJ creates from your options?

Comment: @fhueser thank you, I have added some more info; hope it helps.

Comment: It's really a shot in the dark as I don't see anything that's obviously wrong. Maybe it's due to process forking... check this discussion, maybe it helps https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23689054/problems-passing-system-properties-and-parameters-when-running-java-class-via-gr/23689696#23689696

Comment: @fhueser thank you, that has helped ~ I had forgotten to set the properties also in the Gradle task in build.gradle. However, now both variables hold the value 189 :(

Comment: @fhueser rebuilt and all working! Thank you!!

Comment: nice, glad it helped! :)